# How to implement the Reddit Ads Event Tracking conversion code in an AJAX Form?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ads, reddit, event-tracking

I have a Client that is using Reddit Ads and they would like to use the conversion tracking detailed [here](https://www.reddithelp.com/en/categories/advertising/creating-ads/conversion-pixel#N7).

The code to track a conversion is very straightforward:

```
<script>
rdt(‘track’, ‘EventName’);
</script>
```

However, this Client is using an AJAX Form to capture leads, so there is no page redirect or reload where that code can be added.

The Client had contacted Reddit Support about how to implement this in an AJAX form and Reddit's answer was "Unfortunately, Reddit conversion pixels doesn't support AJAX form."

However, for implementing the Google Ads conversion tracking code in AJAX, I've successfully used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47136898/869849) in the past for a different Client.

So surely there must be a way to do something similar with the Reddit Ads conversion tracking code.

How can I implement the Reddit Ads Event Tracking conversion code in an AJAX Form?

Comment: I haven't used Reddit Ads, but maybe you could place the conversion action `rdt('track', 'EventName');` where the ajax call is being made?

Comment: @shrys:  How would I go about doing that?  Placing `rdt('track', 'EventName');` under `success: function (data)` in the AJAX call produced an error.

Comment: yes, did not expect error

Comment: What was the error? Because it looks like they do support tracking events without loading a new page (for example: button clicks)

Comment: @varunagarwal: So I went back and re-added `rdt('track', 'EventName');` under `success: function (data)` but *above* the Google conversion code and it did not seem to produce an error this time.  Is the way I'm doing it the correct way to implement this?  It does not seem easy to test since it would seem I'd have to wait for a proper Reddit Ads conversion to see if it registers.  Thoughts?